# Dropping images in Qt

Tags: qt

I am looking to be able to take a QImage and drop it into an editing program such as Paint, for example. I've tried setting the mime data to the current image with the following code, but the data doesn't move correctly. The pixmap is displayed correctly, but the drop never happens. If anyone has any advice, that would be much appreciated! Thanks!

```
void LCDWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e) {
    if (e->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
        QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
        QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
        QImage image = renderFramebuffer(lcdState);
        QPixmap mymap = QPixmap::fromImage(image);

        mimeData->setImageData(image);
        drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
        drag->setHotSpot(e->pos());
        drag->setPixmap(mymap);

        drag->exec(Qt::CopyAction | Qt::MoveAction);
        e->accept();
    } else {
        e->ignore();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does Paint ordinarily accept image drops? Try it out by dragging from other applications first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured this out with the following code. The solution is to copy the image to a local file, and then use the path to the file as the copy data.

```
void LCDWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e) {
    if (e->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
        QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
        QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
        QImage image = getImage();
        QPixmap mymap = QPixmap::fromImage(image);

        QString path = QDir::tempPath() + randomString(5) + QStringLiteral(".png");
        image.save(path, "PNG", 0);

        mimeData->setImageData(image);
        mimeData->setUrls(QList<QUrl>() << QUrl::fromLocalFile(path));
        drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
        drag->setHotSpot(e->pos());
        drag->setPixmap(mymap);
        drag->exec(Qt::CopyAction | Qt::MoveAction);
        e->accept();
    } else {
        e->ignore();
    }
}
```